# ROS2 ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_py' from 'rosidl_generator_py'

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I got an ImportError while trying to create a custom interface following the ros2 tutorial  [Creating custom msg and srv files](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html). The project looks like this:

```
src/tutorial_interfaces/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── tutorial_interfaces
├── msg
│   └── Num.msg
├── package.xml
├── src
└── srv
    └── AddThreeInts.srv
```

I followed all steps but at
step [5 Build the tutorial_interfaces package](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html#build-the-tutorial-interfaces-package) the command

`colcon build --packages-select tutorial_interfaces`

failed with the following error message:

```bash
Starting >>> tutorial_interfaces
--- stderr: tutorial_interfaces                             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 8, in <module>
    from rosidl_generator_py import generate_py
ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_py' from 'rosidl_generator_py'
```

Anyone has an idea how to resolve this?

> System: Ubuntu 22.04 +
> ROS2 Humble

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue by installing dependencies

```
pip install empy
pip install lark
```

Basically I looked at the error and saw that it was importing `generate_py` from `rosidl_generator_py`, on my system that was located here:

```
/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/__init__.py
```

So I went to that directory, booted Python, and tried

```
from generate_py_impl import generate_py
```

There I got more details on the error, where the error basically said I was missing Python dependencies.

So you may be missing more dependencies than me, if so, go to that directory and try to import it yourself, and the interpreter will tell you what you are missing.

Comment: Confirmed, this fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3):

I'm Facing the same issue (same system)

System: Ubuntu 22.04 + ROS2 Humble

```
colcon build                                                                                          ─╯
[0.370s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
    'turtlesim' is in: /opt/ros/humble
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
    --allow-overriding turtlesim

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> turtlesim
--- stderr: turtlesim                             
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 8, in <module>
    from rosidl_generator_py import generate_py
ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_py' from 'rosidl_generator_py' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/__init__.py)
gmake[2]: *** [turtlesim__py/CMakeFiles/turtlesim__py.dir/build.make:121: rosidl_generator_py/turtlesim/_turtlesim_s.ep.rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.c] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:706: turtlesim__py/CMakeFiles/turtlesim__py.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< turtlesim [0.48s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.64s]
  1 package failed: turtlesim
  1 package had stderr output: turtlesim
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the same system setup, Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS2 Humble. One more thing is I have anaconda activated. I solved the problem by deactivating conda env and re-build the package. Hopefully, it could help you guys to solve the problem.

Comment: Sadly, didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try to delete the build folder before you re-build the package? Without deleting it, it does not work on my side either.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that step! Now building correctly.

Comment: deactivating conda or commenting conda in bashrc  didnt work in in my case too :( ...

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same error when compiling different packages that had custom interfaces definitions.

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/../../../lib/rosidl_generator_py/rosidl_generator_py", line 8, in <module>
    from rosidl_generator_py import generate_py
ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_py'
```

I don't have `anaconda` or `conda` installed, so I cannot desactivate it. So I fixed it by commenting this line in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
```

I'm sure there could be a better way. But I'm not sure if there is a way to debug which version of Python is used by `colcon` and whether or not that version can import `generate_py`.

Comment: in which CMakeLists.txt did u comment  that... can u please help me ??

Comment: In the package that doesn't build correctly with colcon